# Firebreath plugin, how to read <param > values

Tags: plugins, browser, firebreath

I want to read the `<param>` values of custom plugin

I could not find answer on the internet, what I found was:
https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/NpapiCore/NpapiPlugin.cpp#L76

I see params are stored in `pluginMain->setParams(paramList);`

Can you point how can I access this paramList later? or `pluginMain`
Is there `pluginMain->getParams()`? I could not find reference
Nor I could locate the source for `setParams()`.

The question is, how do I get that parameters from `PluginWindowXXX` or `FB::NpapiPluginXXX` ?

I exported `m_npHost` to `PluginWindowXXX`, set breakpoint in it with gdb but still no success.

All I can think of was:

```
(gdb) p ((FB::Npapi::NpapiBrowserHost)this->m_npHost)->GetValue
$17 = {NPError (const FB::Npapi::NpapiBrowserHost * const, NPNVariable, void *)} 0x7fe435adeff8 <FB::Npapi::NpapiBrowserHost::GetValue(NPNVariable, void*) const>
```

Obviously what I do is wrong but I am stuck,
I am passing this host from `NpapiPluginX11.cpp`

```
pluginWin->setHost(m_npHost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your PluginCore-derived class, you can use either the `getParam` method or the `getParamVariant` method.

From the [FireBreath Source](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginCore/PluginCore.cpp#L93-107):

```
boost::optional<std::string> PluginCore::getParam(const std::string& key) {
    boost::optional<std::string> rval;
    FB::VariantMap::const_iterator fnd = m_params.find(key.c_str());
    if (fnd != m_params.end())
        rval.reset(fnd->second.convert_cast<std::string>());
    return rval;
}

FB::variant FB::PluginCore::getParamVariant( const std::string& key )
{
    FB::VariantMap::const_iterator fnd = m_params.find(key.c_str());
    if (fnd != m_params.end())
        return fnd->second;
    return FB::variant();
}
```

So if it's for sure a string (which it pretty much is, unless it starts with on, in which case it might have been converted to a referenced function), you can use:

```
boost::optional<std::string> mystr = getParam("mystr");
if (mystr) { 
   call_fn_with_string(*mystr);
}
```

Alternately, you can get it as a variant and convert it:

```
FB::variant mystrVal = getParamVariant("mystr");
try {
    call_fn_with_string(mystrVal.convert_cast<std::string>());
} catch (FB::bad_variant_cast &err) {
    // What to do if the cast to string fails
}
```

Answer (score 1):

taxilian's answer is the most correct one as always but I'll give a try. I'm reading params in my MyPluginAPI constructor.

```
MyPluginAPI::MyPluginAPI(const MyPluginPtr& plugin, const FB::BrowserHostPtr& host) : m_plugin(plugin), m_host(host)
{
    string settings; //<param name="settings" value="{'foo':'bar'}">
    settings = plugin->getParam("settings");    
}
```

Comment: thank you both, hasa and taxilian. i tried both approaches and they are working now thanks to you